# Chose best passive/active voice... 1. They greet me cheerfully every morning. a. Every morning I was greeted cheerfully. b. I am greeted cheerfull

Tags: british-english, passive-voice, australian-english, active-voice

In the questions below the sentences have been given in active/passive voice.

From the given alternatives, choose the one which best expresses the given sentence in passive/active voice...

**1. They greet me cheerfully every morning.**

a. Every morning I was greeted cheerfully.

b. I am greeted cheerfully by them every morning.

c. I am being greeted cheerfully by them every morning.

d. Cheerful greeting is done by them every morning to me.

**2. The energy of steam was discovered by James Watt.**

a. James Watt discovered the energy of steam.

b. James Watt was discovered by the energy of steam.

c. James Watt had discovered energy by the steam.

d. The energy of steam discovered James Watt.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Iqrar awan.  I suggest you take the site tour and visit the help center for an overview of how this site operates.

Comment: Everyone should do their own Homework!

Comment: If I answer this question, do I get credit on your homework?

Comment: No,it is not such question like homework.

Answer (score 1):

As for your

> 1b., I am greeted cheerfully by them every morning,

it is the best of the four. Your option "a." is good, too, as long as you changed the tense from past to present, as in

> Every morning, I am greeted by them cheerfully.

As for your

> 2a., James Watt discovered the energy of steam,

it is the best of the four.

And for a parting word of advice: Think of the passive mode (or mood) as a spice which you use sparingly (or, "to be used by you sparingly"!). Too much of the passive voice makes your writing and speaking sound weak and tentative, in my opinion. Using it in moderation, on the other hand (and when the occasion calls for it), can serve a variety of purposes, including enhanced diplomacy! Compare the following two sentences for their diplomatic tone:

> 1. You make me feel bad every time you correct my grammar, especially
>      on my use of the passive tense.

Or,

> 2. I feel bad every time I am corrected by you, especially on my use of the passive tense.

If you think sentence 2 is more diplomatic, then I agree with you. Psychologically, using "I feel bad" is more diplomatic and less accusatory than "you make me feel bad." Leading with *you* tends to incite more defensiveness from the person you are addressing!